# Why does WiX Torch giving me an error code 0279?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, patch, msi-patch

I have a problem when building `.wix` MST difference file. I get the following error:

"*The table definition of target database does not match the table definition updated database. A transform requires that the target database schema match the update database schema*".

I tried finding solution on internet for almost 2 hours but no luck. I know It is probably caused by difference in MSI tables schema but I have no idea how to fix that.